# Incorrect copy of image

Tags: file, image-processing, graphics, bitmap

I need to read an image and to write in back in C++ (to create a copy of it)

I've got a code

```
FILE *filePtr, *filePtr2;    
BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapFileHeader;
BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmapInfoHeader;

filePtr = fopen(path,"rb");
filePtr2 = fopen("output.bmp","wb");

fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,filePtr);
fread(&bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,filePtr);

fwrite(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,filePtr2);
fwrite(&bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,filePtr2);

char *bitmapImage = new char[bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth*3];
fseek(filePtr, bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);

fread(bitmapImage, bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth*3, 1, filePtr);
fwrite(bitmapImage, bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth*3, 1, filePtr2);
```

But the resulting image is weight less than the source. I can open it in ImageViewer, but the last rows of image are not displaying.

If i change the multiplying by 3 to the multiplying by 4 everywhere in the code, the resulted image viewed with no problem but the size is larger then the source has.

biBitCount = 24 that's why I'm multiplying by 3, cause  (Every three bytes in the bitmap’s data field represent the relative intensities of blue, green and red for (BGR) every pixel.)

Comment: Is the `fseek()` line right? Do you need to convert bfOffBits to a number of bytes instead? We might need to know more about the format of the file, though - in particular, does it include padding anywhere, for example to make each row a certain number of bytes?

Comment: guess i've found the mistake. I didnt add flose() at the end :-D

Comment: lol, that still isnt working. I get the normal result on the big image (800x600) but with the same cropped image (400x300) as a source, the result is 2 bytes smaller.

Comment: About bfOfBits, the header in the result is ok, the problem is the last line of image (the top of the image). looks like the problem is somewhere in the lines of reading or writing the image dataPoints?

Comment: "does it include padding anywhere, for example to make each row a certain number of bytes?" - can u say it with another words?

Comment: If each pixel takes 3 bytes, and the width of your image is 7 pixels, that's 21 bytes per row. It wouldn't be unheard of for an image file format to pad a row up to 24 bytes so that the next row starts on a 32-bit boundary. If it does something like that, then simply calculating width*height*3 will not give you the total number of bytes you need to read.

Comment: the problem about padding is exactly what i have!! Look, i've wrote a function, that calculates the total amount of all padding bytes: int add = bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage - ( bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight * bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 ); but in the image 4 pixels width (2 pix height) this function returns to me 2 (bytes). This two padding bytes goes after all image data, but not after the each row. I've found that padding bytes after the row is width % 4. I've got 0, and for my case that is ok. But where are these two last padding bytes came from??

Comment: THis may be a really stupid question, but is there a reason that (at least from your question) "I need to read an image and to write in back in C++ (to create a copy of it)", that you aren't simply reading in the file byte for byte, and simply writing it back out byte-for-byte!  Why are you bothering to decode the bitmap stuff?

Comment: I need to make some image processing before writing the image back